# send file to another specific phone without bluetooth device selection

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I have a requirement to send a specified file(e.g., test1.pg) to all the paired mobile phones(without any confirmation). I don't want the Bluetooth Device selection window to be displayed and selecting the device from there. I have the following code but what happens is it shows the Bluetooth Device Selector screen and it expects to select the device and the file is being sent. Pls find below the piece of code that I am intending to execute for all the connected mobile phones.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test1.jpg");
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
    sendIntent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device.getAddress());
    sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.broadcom.bt.app.opp.OppLauncherActivity");
    //sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.bluetooth", "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity");
//  sendIntent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

and my AndroidManifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bt_test2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:label="BLUETOOTH"></permission>
<permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"></permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:debuggable="true">
<activity
android:name="com.example.bt_test2.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.broadcom.bt.app.opp.OppLauncherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: all your code just show that you start a activity, nothing else.

Comment: yes I start the activity but the intent is ACTION_SEND, so it should send the file. In my case it is sending the specified file but it is expecting me to select the device which I dont want to do. I appreciate if you pls provide code/solution that is missing in the above code.